# Inputting (a lot of )data into a dataframe one row at a time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-wrangling

I'm using python. Some 2D numpy arrays are stored in individual rows of a Series. They are 30x30 images. It looks something like this:

```
     pixels
0    [[23,4,54...],[54,6,7...],[........]]
1    [[65,54,255,55,...],[43,54,6...],[......]]
...
...
...
7000 [[........]]
```

For each row in the Series, I want to take these 2D arrays, flatten them to 1D, take the values and assign them to the columns of one row in data frame. Each row will have 30x30 = 900pixels each, storing the values of each pixel. Like this:

```
    pixel1    pixel2    pixel3...    pixel900
0       23         4        54             77
1       65        54       255             33
...
...
...
```

I'm using an elaborate function that extracts one row from the series at a time, flattens the array, converts it to a Series again, and appends it to a dataframe. It takes sooo long. I'm sure there must be a faster way. I'm using this code:

```
def prep_pixels(X):
    # X is a series
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(len(X.index)): #iterate through the whole series
        df = df.append(pd.Series(X[i].flatten()), ignore_index=True) 
    return df
```

EDIT:
Upon request from a user, I will provide code with how I ended up in this rut in the first place :D

```
#reading the files
filepath = 'dataset.pickle'
data_np = pd.read_pickle(filepath)
print(data_np[0])
```

Output:

```
 [array([[255, 248, 253, 255, 251, 253, 254, 236, 220, 217, 191, 145, 139,
        185, 216, 227, 252, 251, 254, 248, 251, 236, 221, 222, 213, 175,
        120,  75,  74, 209],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
         58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
         21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
         12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
         53,  58,  64, 124],
    ... 30 rows of 30 pixels
    ...
    ... last row coming up ...
    [255, 255, 254, 254, 253, 252, 253, 254, 255, 255, 254, 252, 249,
    249, 251, 213, 126, 178, 231, 252, 248, 250, 254, 254, 252, 253,
    255, 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8), 'क']
```

The last symbol in this list is the character that this image represents. It's the 'label'. It's supervised learning using CNNs. Anyway, I need them to be in the other format I described to be able to work with them. This is how I'm handling this data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data_np, columns=['pixels','labels'])
def prep_pixels(X):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(len(X.index)): #iterate through whole series
        df = df.append(pd.Series(X[i].ravel()), ignore_index=True)  
    return df

X = prep_pixels(data['pixels'])
y = data['labels']
```

EDIT: a user suggested that I use a mutable datatype to do this procedure. They said that it might speed things up because the computation does not need to make copies of data. I used some nested for loops and it cut the time to half (1 min 22 sec instead of 3 min). I still feel like its pathetic, given that my dataset has just 7000, 30x30 pixel images. Or, maybe I'm just new to data wrangling.

Here is the code I used. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions:

```
filepath = 'dataset.pickle'
data_np = pd.read_pickle(filepath)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in range(IMG_ROW):   
    for col in range(IMG_COL):
        pixel=[]
        for img in range(len(data_np)):
            pixel.append(data_np[img][0][row][col]) 
        columns = pd.Series(pixel, name=col)
        df = pd.concat([df, columns], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: Try using `ravel()` instead of `flatten()`. It does not returns a copy and hence is faster.

Comment: Hi, I just tried it. Thank you, I didn't know that. 
It still takes quite a while, and my data set has just 7000, 30x30 pixel, black&white images. I think this procedure I'm using is not the most efficient one. 
Thank you anyway.

Comment: Can you add code to create an actual example of one of the arrays to your question? There could be faster ways, but I am not sure exactly how you have a Series with multiple 2D arrays. As far as I can test, that isn't possible. The fastest way would be to not put them in a Series object in the first place, if that is possible :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Ok I will modify the post to include code now. 
The problem is that these images are stored in a file, and when I extract them, they become a pandas object like this. 
The application is for computer vision. Just FYI

Comment: How much time does current implementation take ?

Comment: There are 7000 images, and it takes 3min and 43 seconds to do run this little piece of code. I'm on a very fast rig, that is designed for deep learning applications. As you can see, it gets the work done, but the inefficiency of this code is unbearable.

Comment: Unless you are using the GPUs (which Pandas, nor numpy does not) the fact that your rig is fast will have little impact in managing the speed of the ram. 

Did you just try a  pd.DataFrame(data=data), I don't think you can do faster than that

Comment: a possible performance gain would be to build up the data in a mutable data structure like a list rather than a data fame (which is immutable) then convert it to a data frame. means you don't copy the data frame each time you append to it

Comment: Hi Leon and Andrew, 
Thank you for your feedback. I did try the pd.DataFrame(data=data) strategy first, but it didn't work out. The data needs to be in this specific way, one row in a dataframe contains ALL the pixels in the image, flattened. 

Thank you Andrew, that was some valuable insight. I tried using nested for loops, and it took half the time (1min 22 sec). I still feel like this is lengthy, or maybe I'm just new to data wrangling.

Comment: I think Andrew's point, and what I've usually read, is to save the conversion to a frame for last.  In your last code example, append the `columns` to a list inside the loop, then call `pd.DataFrame` after the loop.  (Maybe some reshaping or transposing is needed.)

Also, how does `flatX=X.apply(lambda x: x.flatten())`, `pd.DataFrame(item for item in flatX)` perform?

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting `timeit` results of about 1/4 of the time using:

```
flatX = X.apply(lambda x: x.flatten())
pd.DataFrame(item for item in flatX)
```

See also 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901018/convert-pandas-series-of-lists-to-dataframe
for some possibly better options for the second line.

(Regarding my earlier comment, I don't get any real savings by just dataframe-ing at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

Or you walk through each column, see Test3.
Mind in general:

- ".apply()" is slower than list comprehension, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas.
- Column-wise is faster than row-wise in the standard case of #rows > #columns (of course).
- Use numpy if you can.

Results:

- Test1: 232.96580633900157 (@IsuShrestha, flatten each row, append row-wise)
- Test2: 6.919965944998694 (@BenReiniger, flatten each row)
- Test3: 0.3909464059997845 (append column-wise = over all rows in one go = 29 appends)

(AMD A8-3870 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics, 3000 MHz, 4 cores, 4 logical processors, 8 GB memory, Windows 10 64bit)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-python
from timeit import default_timer as timer


row = [np.array([
    [255, 248, 253, 255, 251, 253, 254, 236, 220, 217, 191, 145, 139,
    185, 216, 227, 252, 251, 254, 248, 251, 236, 221, 222, 213, 175,
    120,  75,  74, 209],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],       
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],    
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],
       [255, 255, 255, 248, 252, 255, 202,  88,  15,  16,  14,  11,  11,
     12,  12,  20,  40,  46,  38,  43,  40,  25,  21,  19,  17,  35,
     53,  58,  64, 124],
       [255, 253, 254, 253, 252, 254, 223, 146,  87,  75,  58,  30,  27,
     58,  86, 116, 157, 168, 164, 165, 167, 136,  96,  71,  59,  49,
     21,   9,  27, 144],         
    [255, 255, 254, 254, 253, 252, 253, 254, 255, 255, 254, 252, 249,
    249, 251, 213, 126, 178, 231, 252, 248, 250, 254, 254, 252, 253,
    255, 255, 255, 255]
    ], dtype='uint8'), "क"]



data_np = []
for i in range(7000):
    data_np.append(row)
    
    

data = pd.DataFrame(data_np, columns=['pixels','labels'])


# Test1 (@IsuShrestha, flatten each row, append row-wise)
def prep_pixels(X):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(len(X.index)): #iterate through whole series
        df = df.append(pd.Series(X[i].ravel()), ignore_index=True)  
    return df
start = timer()
test = prep_pixels(data['pixels'])
print(timer()-start)
print(test.shape)
# 232.96580633900157
# (7000, 900)


# Test2 (@BenReiniger, flatten each row)
def prep_pixels2(X):
    flatX = X.apply(lambda x: x.flatten())
    return pd.DataFrame(row for row in flatX)
start = timer()
test2 = prep_pixels2(data['pixels'])
print(timer()-start)
print(test2.shape)
# 6.919965944998694
# (7000, 900)


# Test3 (append column-wise = over all rows in one go = 29 appends)
def prep_pixels3(X):
    test = np.array([x[0] for x in X])
    for i in range(len(X[0])-1):
        # print(i)
        test = np.append(arr=test, values=np.array([x[i+1] for x in X]), axis=1)
    return pd.DataFrame(test)
start = timer()
test3 = prep_pixels3(data['pixels'].to_numpy())
print(timer()-start)
print(test3.shape)
# 0.3909464059997845
# (7000, 900)
```